# Is "Dict" a keyword in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

In the codebase I'm looking at at work, there's a line

```
values = Dict[int, List[QuantityClass]]
```

I cannot find where `Dict` is defined anywhere in the codebase when I did a grep, and I don't think it's a keyword in Python? This isn't a keyword right? It looks like some kind of custom `dictionary`, analogous to the native `dict`, but I'm not able to find its definition with a grep.

Comment: `from typing import Dict`. It is for type hinting, though now no longer needed since it can be done with`dict[str, str]` instead.

Comment: most probably you are using `from typing import *` and this is from where you got `Dict`

Comment: @sahasrara62 ahh yes there is indeed the `from typing import *`. no wonder why it illuded my grep attempts

Comment: @roulette01 i guess time to refactor imports

Comment: Btw, even `dict` is not a keyword. It is a predefined symbol. If it were a keyword, you would be unable to redefine it  `for` is a keyword. And that is the reason why, even if you wanted to, you could not `for=12`. It means nothing syntaxically. While, even if you shouldn't, you can `dict=12`. Because it is just a syntaxically correct `symbol` `EQUAL` `number` sequence. So `dict` is just a symbol, not a keyword (word that help structure syntax, such as `for`, `if`, `def`, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the comments made we want to answer. Per the comments, `Dict` is for type hinting and comes from `from typing import Dict` (or in your case `from typing import *`).

That being said, I feel it is relevant to share a way to help debug this in the future instead of `grep`.

If you face this again and ask:

> What is this?

You can use `help` to understand what something is:

```py
from typing import *
help(Dict)
```

This of course only works if the object is in scope, but it seems your main question was figuring out where something came from which you saw in code.

Comment: ah I wasn't aware of `help` (I don't use Python often). That's really useful! Also wasn't aware of what was in `typing` either, otherwise I would've known to look in there

Comment: I don't use `help(...)` often but `dir(...)` I use every time I program in Python :) (They serve different purposes but the second is more handy than the first)

Comment: So in this case, what exactly is "values" and how can it used (It's not actaully used in the codebase I'm looking at)? I printed its type and the output is `<class 'typing._GenericAlias'>`. So it's just an alias for a type? So basically later on I could, say, annotate a parameter in a function as this type?

Comment: Its used for type annotations. Solely to make your code more readable and help intelli-sense. I.e. `my_keys: Dict[str, str] = {"some_key": "some_val"}`.  It is slightly outdated because you can now just do `my_keys: dict[str, str] = {"some_key": "some_val"}` in I believe 3.10+. But you should also never `import *`